# Is there a website or tool that allows tracking of US state lines crossed?

Tags: usa, online-resources

http://www.mob-rule.com/ allows a user to track the US counties they have traveled to and produces a nice map of the results.

I have a traveling goal of crossing all the US state land borders. For example, to complete the state of Idaho, I would need to cross the WA/ID, OR/ID, NV/ID, UT/ID, WY/ID, and MT/ID borders. Is there something similar to the link above for tracking the state lines that someone has crossed? Ideally it would in some way "color in" a border once you've logged that you've crossed it.

Comment: Never heard of anything like it, but it sounds like a nice weekend project for a developer.

Comment: You could use a paper map and a sharpie and plaster the result to a wall at your home?

Comment: As a former GIS professional (does that make me a GIS amateur?), I've now decided to do this for myself.  For interest I posted your question in the [gis.se] Stack Exchange chat

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I've done NY/CT, NY/NJ, NJ/PA, PA/DE, PA/MD, DE/MD, DE/NJ, MD/WV, VA/WV, VA/MD, MD/DC, VA/DC. The last five I've done on foot.

Comment: @Erik I could, but ideally I'd like it somewhere online so that I could compete with friends!

Comment: There's probably a fun graph theory question in here too.

Comment: @Midavalo that probably wont do much good, the GIS-chat is quite dead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a cellphone with data, you could enable Google Timeline which is compatible with Android iPhone/iPad and computers.

Once enabled it will track and record all your movements which then you can view in google maps (you can even receive a monthly report if you want). The issue is that the state lines when you are zoomed in are so faint that is hard to see them, but on the other hand, you can download your timeline data as a KML file (and other formats) which can be opened in google earth which can show clearer borders.

Here is an example of some data I collected from my phone, the red dots are stops I made:

[image]

More information of Google Timeline: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6258979?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Hope this helps.